# D3.js: display limited number of ticks

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to use `d3.ticks`. [According to the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks), I should be able to restrict the number of ticks displayed on the axis.

However, this doesn't seem to restrict the number of ticks at all:

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").ticks(2)
```

Is it because my scale is ordinal?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/9tfD2/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`axis.ticks` only works when the underlying scale implements a `ticks` function, which ordinal scales do not.  By default, the axis ticks for an ordinal scale are comprised of the scale's domain, but you can override this by supplying explicit tick values with [axis.tickValues](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues).

Comment: Thanks. This was driving me nuts.

Comment: any idae how to set the number of them and allow to to stay auto generated?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation also says (in the part for scales)

> The specified count is only a hint; the scale may return more or fewer values depending on the input domain.

This is what's happening here -- for the ordinal scale, all the values are taken.

You can however override this by providing explicit tick values, e.g.

```
d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").tickValues(["12am", "8pm"])
```