# D3js:Unable to create my desired amount of ticks in x Axis

Tags: d3.js

I have this chart which is creating 10 ticks values in the x axes. I want it to have 5 ticks. I tried the `.ticks(5)` method, but it is not working. Can you please help me figure out why is it not working or how can I accomplish it?

Here is the running snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  //Mobile or not?
  
  function isMobileDevice() {
    return (typeof window.orientation !== "undefined") || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('IEMobile') !== -1);
  };


  //print in console wether I'm on mobile or desktop
  
  (function(){
    if(isMobileDevice()){
      console.log("This device is a mobile");
    }
    else{
      console.log("This device is a PC or laptop");
    }
  })();

  function textSetter(){

    if(isMobileDevice()){

      if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        return textSize =  30
      }
      
      else{
        return textSize = 15
      }
    }
    
    else{
      return ()=> window.innerWidth  < 785 ?  textSize = 11 :  textSize = 20
      
    }
  }


   //This will set the height depending on landscape or portrait//
  function heightSetter(){

    if(isMobileDevice()){
  //landscape or not//
      if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        return 40
      }

      else{
        return 20
      }
    }
//But if not, then it check if browser is full expanded or not and set styles accordingly.  
    else{
      return ()=> window.innerWidth  < 785 ? "11px" : "20px"
    }
  }   
   
  var ticksDataArray = [
    [
      {country: "India", growth: 35},
      {country: "Chile",growth: 30},
      {country: "Spain",growth: 25},
      {country: "US",growth: 20},
      {country: "France",growth: 15},

    ]
  ]; 
 
  function draw(chartDiv, ticksArray) {

    var margin = {
    top: 15,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
    };

  var width = $(chartDiv).width() - margin.left/2 - margin.right * 10;

  var height = $(chartDiv).height() - margin.top - (margin.bottom*3.5);


  var data = ticksArray;

  function heightSetter(){

    if(isMobileDevice()){
      if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        return [margin.bottom, (height)]
      }

      else{
        return [margin.bottom, (height*1.2)]
      }
    }

    else{
      return [margin.bottom, (height)]
    }
  }  

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width + 50 ])

    var yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range(heightSetter()).padding(.38)


   function svgGtranslater(){

    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
      return heightJC =  (margin.top) + (margin.bottom*2)
      console.log("portrait mode")
    }

    else{
      return heightJC =  margin.top + margin.bottom *.5
      console.log("landscape mode or desktop")
    }
  }

   svgGtranslater();

  var svg = d3.select(chartDiv)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right * 10)
  .attr("height", ()=> isMobileDevice ? height + margin.top + (margin.bottom*5) : height + margin.top + (margin.bottom*3.5))
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (margin.left * 4)  + "," + heightJC + ")")

  data.forEach(function(d) {
  return d.growth = +d.growth;
  });

  yScale.domain(data.map(d => d.country))

  xScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.growth)])

  function yAxistranslater(){

    if(isMobileDevice()){
      if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        return heightTwo = height;
      }

      else{
        return heightTwo = height*1.2;
      }
    }

    else{
      return heightTwo = height;
    }
  }
  
  //GO translater :D!
  yAxistranslater()


  var xAxis = svg.append("g")
    .style("font-size", textSetter())

  .attr("class", "xAxis", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + heightTwo + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(5)
    .tickPadding(5).tickFormat(d => d + "%"))
    

  var yAxis = svg.append("g") 
      .style("font-size", textSetter())
      .attr("class", "yAxis", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("stroke", "transparent")
      .attr("stroke-width", 4)
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
      .attr("x", 0.5)
      .attr("y", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.country)
      })
      .attr("width", 0)
      .transition()
      .duration(3800)
      .delay((d, i) => (i + 1) * 200)
      .ease(d3.easeElastic)
      .attr("width", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.growth)
      })
      .style("fill", "#00338D")
      .on('end', function() {
      d3.select(this)
      .on("mouseover", function() {
      d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(600)
      .attr("stroke", "#6D2077")
      .attr("stroke-width", 3)
      .style("fill", "#6D2077")
      d3.selectAll(".textCircle")
      .transition()
      .duration(600)
      .attr("r", yScale.bandwidth() / 1.9)
      .attr("stroke", "#6D2077")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
      d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(600)
      .attr("stroke", "transparent")
      .attr("stroke-width", 0)
      .style("fill", "#00338D")
      d3.selectAll(".textCircle")
      .transition().duration(600)
      .attr("r", yScale.bandwidth() / 2)
      .attr("stroke", "transparent")
      })
      })


    var newG4text = svg.append("g").attr("class","newG4text")

      newG4text.selectAll(".text")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", d => xScale(d.growth))
      .attr("y", d => yScale(d.country) + yScale.bandwidth()/2)
      .attr("dx","-3em")
      .attr("dy",".4em")
      .style("font-size", textSetter()) 
      .style("fill","#FFF")
      .style("font-weight","bold")
      .text(d=>d.growth + "%")

    //main Title
    svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", (width / 2))             
    .attr("y", 10 )
    .attr("dy", 10 )
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
    .attr("fill", "#00338D") 
    .style("font-size", textSize*1.5) 
    .text("Technology growth on the Current Year ");
    } 

  draw("body",ticksDataArray[0]); 

  function redraw(){
    draw("body",ticksDataArray[0]); 
  } 

 $(window).resize(function() {
   $("body").empty();
   redraw();     
   });

})
```

```css
html{ 
    height: 98%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  body{
    min-height: 98%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  svg{
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    shape-rendering:geometricPrecision;
  }
```

```html
<meta country="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<!--tether.min.css-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.4/css/tether.min.css" />

<!--jquery.min.js-->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--d3.min.js 4.13.0-->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
 
<!--bootstrap.min.css-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<!--jquery.min.js again-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you add your `xScale` as well? Its advisable to create a working snippet with no missing variables.

Comment: @Shashank, I created the running snippet,  :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3.js: display limited number of ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834053/d3-js-display-limited-number-of-ticks)

Comment: This has been asked multiple times. Try using `tickValues` to provide the actual ticks. If you read the second answer in the link there (also mentioned [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/issues/61) by Mike), the count in `.ticks(count)` is just a hint and not an actual value. If you face issues using .tickValues do let me know and I'll help you out.

Comment: @Shashank, it returns me very not expected values.

Comment: Do you know what ticks you want on the xAxis?

Comment: Yes, I need 5 ticks

´.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks( 3 ).tickFormat(d=>d + "+%"))´  returns:
0%    10%   20   %30+%

´.call(d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks( 5 ).tickFormat(d=>d + "+%"))´  returns 

0% 5% 10% 15% 20% 25% 30% 35%.

The weirdest part for me is that .ticks( 3 ) returns 4 ticks

I can't manage to display 5 ticks. Can you please tell me why is this behavior? Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you go through the [possible duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834053/d3-js-display-limited-number-of-ticks) I referred to? Also, I did mention in my comment above about that behavior. Please go through it again.